# Accessing "this" inside an object

Tags: javascript, oop

I'm having some trouble in a pretty big body of code I've been writing, and I've boiled it down to this:

```
var Thing = function(argument){
    this.property = argument;
    this.obj = {
        func: function(){
            return this;
        }
    };
    this.func = function(){
        return this;
    };
};
```

I need to access `this.property` inside `obj.func()`. However, the value of `this` isn't what I expect it to be:

```
> var thing = new Thing("value")
> thing.func()
Thing {property: "value", obj: Object, func: function}
> thing.obj.func()
Object {func: function}
```

When I instantiate an instance called "thing" and call `thing.func()`, `this` holds the current instance of `Thing`, as it should. But when I call `thing.obj.func()`, it holds the value of `thing.obj`. What's going on? How do I access that value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var thing = new Thing('value')
thing.obj.func() // this inside func will be the object before .func, which is thing.obj
```

One solution is to bind the function to your object:

```
var Thing = function(argument){
    this.property = argument;
    this.obj = {
        func: function(){
            return this;
        }.bind(this);    // bind it to the current object
    };
    this.func = function(){
        return this;
    };
};
```

Alternatively you could use a closure with a private copy of `this`:

```
var Thing = function(argument){
    var that = this;
    this.property = argument;
    this.obj = {
        func: function(){
            return that;
        }
    };
    this.func = function(){
        return this;
    };
};
```

Comment: I like the `.bind(this)` solution, because it means the majority of my other code (there's a lot more than I included in the question) can stay unchanged.

Comment: @Dan Use `bind` carefully, it's not supported by IE8 and below.

Answer (score 4):

Declare a local variable in the constructor, and assign it the value of `this`:

```
var Thing = function(argument){
    var theThing = this;
```

You can then use "theThing" to refer to the constructed object in those functions.

In your existing code, when you call `thing.obj.func()`, the value of `this` in the function will indeed be `this.obj`.  That's because the value of `this` is determined based on the circumstances of the function call. In that case, the reference to the function ("func") is obtained by traversing its property name on the "obj" object. Therefore, the "obj" object is what `this` references.

Comment: I'd suggest changing the variable's name. `self` is reserved in [Gecko browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.self) for the window object.

Comment: @matewka it's not "reserved"; it's used as an alias for `window` but it's a perfectly legal variable name. However I'll change it; personally I wouldn't use it anyway :)

Comment: @matewka I would prefer a name that actually means something; the common use of "self" or (worse) "that" kind-of drives me nuts, but it's a convention on SO so I go with the flow.

Comment: My suggestion would be to borrow the name from PHP's singletons: "instance".

Answer (score 1):

That's the way the `this` context works in Javascript. You'd need to store an intermediate reference to Thing:

```
var Thing = function(argument){
    var self = this;
    this.property = argument;
    this.obj = {
        func: function(){
            return self;
        }
    };
    this.func = function(){
        return self;
    };
};
```

Comment: `this` has nothing to do with scope, it's a parameter of an execution context that is set by the call (or *bind*).

Answer (score 0):

`this` refers to the object which owns the function by default, in this case `obj`. Here is a workaround :

```
thing.obj.func.call(thing);
```